# Remove Image From HTML Email Gmail Preview - Python Mail

Tags: python, html-email

Hello trying to send **HTML Email** with python but when the image is shown as **downloadable** in the email preview with the name "noname"

[image: email preview]

My Code is :

```py
msg = EmailMessage()

msg['Subject'] = 'Hello there - Test'
msg['From'] = 'Mail 1 <mail1@gmail.com>'
msg['To'] = 'Mail 2 <mail2@ceb-eg.com>'

msg.set_content('This is a plain text body.')

image_cid = make_msgid()

msg.add_alternative(f"""\
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <a href="#"><img src="cid:{image_cid[1:-1]}" alt="Congratulations" ></a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
""", subtype='html')

with open('image-1.png', 'rb') as img:

    maintype, subtype = mimetypes.guess_type(img.name)[0].split('/')
    msg.get_payload()[1].add_related(img.read(), maintype=maintype, subtype=subtype, cid=image_cid)
```

I need to hide this preview like a logo in normal emails and if we cant how can I rename it?

Comment: It seems like mime type issue. Could you provide `maintype` and `subtype` values?

Comment: I used ```.guess_type``` Function to determine the type of image